# can't get pydot to find graphviz on windows 10

Tags: python, graphviz, random-forest, pydot

I'm trying to run a Random Forest analysis on Python 2.7 and I get this error while trying to create the graph of the decision trees. 
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHsra.jpg)

I've tried reinstalling pydot and graphviz in alternating orders and I've also tried adding dot.exe to my system variables path with the value as C:\Program Files(x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\

I'm fairly new to coding so I'd appreciate if you can explain the steps in detail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When changing the `PATH` variable (or any other system variable for that matter), the applications using this variables must be restarted in order to see the new values. Alternatively, log out completely and log back in.

The application (in this case Python) should now be able to call the programs in `C:\Program Files(x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\`. Hope this solves it!

Comment: Thanks! I found the problem was in my Anaconda installation since my jupyter notebook was using a different python installation. Thanks for the reply!